# Правописание НЕ с причастием в предложении

Tags: орфография, частица-не

В тени липы сидела опечаленная Олюшка. Сквозь густую листву к ней никак не мог пробиться солнечный луч, и пушистая головенка оставалась (не)поглаженной.

Как написать НЕ с причастием в этом предложении: по правилам или по смыслу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**...пушистая головенка оставалась не поглаженной.**

Здесь лучше выбрать смысловой вариант, то есть отрицание действия, а не утверждение результата действия.

Пример:  Поэтому в дождливую осень хлеб с полей **оставался не убранным**, или гнил в суслонах, картошка оставалась **не выкопанной**, лён **не выдерганным**. [Д. И. Саврасов. Умирание деревни (2003-2008)

Comment: А почему лучше, Жасмин?

Comment: Здесь авторский вариант употребления причастия, и он выражает именно отсутствие действия.  Обычно мы говорим о "непоглаженном белье". Или вот еще: Пришел небритый, непоглаженный (в непоглаженном/мятом костюме). Вот в этих случаях мы имеем дело с результатом действия, причастие  близко по значению к прилагательному.

Comment: Спасибо! Интересно, а я тоже слитное написание воспринимаю как близкое к прилагательному, но НЕ воспринимаю как раз "непоглаженную" как результат действия. Но это, видимо, индивидуально. Интересно было понять Вашу логику. :)

Comment: @Jasmin Вы прям озадачили меня. Буду думу думати, что же я имею в виду на самом деле: отсутствие действия или его результат. Как бы так сориентироваться на мнение читателей, чтобы написание не цепляло.

Comment: Ну вот я на месте читателей представляю, что  значение здесь такое:  солнышко голову не погладило, не приласкало ребенка. Это и есть смысловое решение. А по правилам НЕ с причастиями без зависимых слов должно писаться слитно.